# What is wrong with my hibiscus?

Tags: diseases, pests, hibiscus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbcs1.jpg)[image][image][image]

The growth on this little tree seems much slower than it's sibling. The leaves appear to be growing very misshapen and start to curl under. It's almost as if it's being eaten along the edges. There are also little holes in them along the veins of the leaf.

I have sprayed weekly with neem oil. That didn't seem to help. I have used insecticidal soap. Didn't help. I've used a 3in1 spray for diseases and pests. Didn't help. I took every leaf off the tree and continued neem oil spray weekly. The leaves are coming back some but still grow misshapen and with holes and curling.  It isn't every leaf, but more than 75% of the entire tree.